# Keep values fom labels by jquery after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html

Hello i got this code

```
<div class="values"><span>Labels :</span><span class="selected"></span>
</div>
<div id='main'>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="values">
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label data-name="1">a</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label data-name="2">b</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label data-name="3">c</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
        <div class="values">
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label data-name="1">d</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label data-name="2">e</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2" />
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <label data-name="3">f</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function labelsValue(selected) {
        var selected = $('#main input[type="checkbox"]').filter(':checked').map(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).next().attr('data-name'));

        }).get();

       $('.labels .values').text(selected.join(', '));       
    }

    $('input').on('change', function() {
        labelsValue($(this));
    });
```

And i have dynimicly display values from labels by chekcbox click, but when i refresh the page checkboxes are checked but lables not read. Data to label and input are read from php arrays.

How to change this code to red values from labels by jquery after page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 Local Storage or Session Storage to remember label values even after page refresh.